# Disable a dropdown when a checkbox has been selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a checkbox and a dropdown menu inside my application:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary" id="ProxyCheckbox">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(a => a.IsProxy)
                    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.IsProxy, "Is Proxy?")
                    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.IsProxy)
                </div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend style="display: none">Add Membership Form</legend>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SocietyId, new { @class = "hidden" })
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SocietyId, societies.Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = s.SocietyName,
                Value = s.SocietyId.ToString()
            }), "Please select a society...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "proxySelect" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SocietyId, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I have written some JQuery to disable the dropdownmenu, when you select the checkbox. But for some reason its not working. I am using Boostrap 3.

```
$(document).on('click', '#ProxyCheckbox', function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $('#proxySelect').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('#proxySelect').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
```

Comment: A `<select>` does not have a `checked` property. I'm guessing you want `if ($'#AgreementNumberRequired').is(':checked')) { ... }` (and you handle the `change` event, not the `click` event of the `<select>`. But what is the point of this - disabled controls do not submit a value

Comment: @StephenMuecke If you select the checkbox , then the list is disabled. The reason behind this is that I dont want the user to access the dropdown when the checkbox is selected.

Comment: That makes no sense. What is the point of a `<select>` is it does not post a value (and your model will be invalid). And then what happens if the user uses the keyboard to navigate through the options (they want to select the 3rd option, but you disabled it when the 1st one is selected)

Comment: It will post a value, but if you select Is a Proxy checkbox then it is disabled. There is another field at the top, which I am adding.

Comment: What other field?

Comment: And what is the point of the `@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.IsProxy)` - you already have a checkbox bound to that property and the hidden input is pointless since it will be ignored

Comment: The other field is called Name. So if you enter a Name, then if the Checkbox is selected then the dropdown is disabled. but if you dont its not disabled. I am just following the previous markup that was on the page for the rest of the form elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#ProxyCheckbox is the DIV containing the checkbox.

First assign an ID to the IsProxy checkbox, for example

```
id="IsProxy"
```

Then, if you want to maintain the click event on the div:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ProxyCheckbox', function () {
    $('#proxySelect').prop('disabled', $('#IsProxy').is(':checked'));
 });
```

If you want to set the event on the checkbox itself:

```
$('#IsProxy').click(function(){
    $('#proxySelect').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
};
```

## Update:

In the previous answer i used "removeProp", but, as suggested by Rob, it doesnt work with disabled or other built-in properties: http://api.jquery.com/removeprop/

So i updated the answer to use a more elegant way, with just a 1 line instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Slight change to the code above:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ProxyCheckbox', function () {
        if ($("#IsProxy").is(':checked')) {
            $('#proxySelect').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#proxySelect').**removeAttr**('disabled');
        }
 });
```